# How to override hitTest to select UITableView Rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

How do I allow my tableView to be selectable by overriding hitTest?

I have a tableview that lives outside of bounds of its superview so I need to override hitTest of the view containing the superview. However, when I pass the tableview's hittest I can only scroll and not tap on a row.

```
 public override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let pointInTableview = tableView.convert(point, from: self)
    guard tableView.bounds.contains(pointInTableview) else {
      return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    return tableView.hitTest(pointInTableview, with: event)
  }
```

The datasource and delegates are set. If I manually call tableview.selectRowAt(..) I am able to receive the delegate callback.

[Gif of demo](https://giphy.com/gifs/ar24xYrMPdeWEX95BX)

The VC View is the view that is overriding hitTest. We are trying to pass the  touches to the tableview because the tableview is outside the bounds of the view it lives in.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Your post is hard to follow. What does your view hierarchy look like? Which view overrides `hitTest(_:with:)`?

Comment: @RobC I have added a diagram

Comment: Your code above looks fine. I think something is wrong with your delegate. Can you share your code? I would post your viewController code, tableView delegate code, and any other UIView subclasses you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the hitTest.

My VC View had a tap gesture to close keyboards. This tap gesture was cancelling the tableview's tap gesture.

Ref: https://kakubei.github.io/2016/02/24/Tap-Gesture-and-TableView/